# Creating a Google map in iOS that doesn't fit the whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps SDK to generate a map in my UIViewController but it's generating a map on the whole screen. I only need it to create a map on half the screen. How do I accomplish that?

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView = GMSMapView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // User Location
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                              longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 9.1)

        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not set `self.view` outside of the `loadView` method.

The proper solution here is to create the map view once in `viewDidLoad`. Add it as a subview of `self.view` instead of assigning it to `self.view`. Set its frame once in `viewWillAppear`. Set the frame to be half the screen as needed.

Then if needed, update the map view's location in your `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Steps to solve this.

1. create a subview , add the proper constrains to it 
   [set constraints for the map view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVJaj.png)
2. create @IBoutlet for your map view , make sure to change the type of it to be   GMSMapView! instead of the regular UIView type!

   `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!`
3. let your mapView and from the identity inspector , change the type also and make it  GMSMapView!
   [change the class type of the mapview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNj28.png)
4. No need to initialize anywhere now, simply use the mapView you connected with the storyboard and it will start working.

Answer (score 1):

Create another view on your ViewController that is exactly the size you want, then instead of:
 `self.view = mapView`
you can do `self.(insert your new view name here) = mapView`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main issue

```
self.view = mapView
```

You are setting your mapView as self.view which means full Size of view that appear on Screen

instead do like in didLoad

```
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

and set it frame in willAppear or didAppear

```
mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: self.view.frame.size.height/2)
```